# using classes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I am using **CodeIgniter**, and I have a PHP class for building the reports of my system(Report). This class uses another class, for building the graphics of this reports(ReportG).

I store class Report as library, but inside this class I use objects and methods of **ReportG**.

I need to rewrite my Report class to load this class(ReportG) from library?

Is there any way to use classes in CodeIgniter in the traditional way:

```
$a = new MyClass();
$a->GetGraphics();
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using traditional method?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is, but you have to forgo the use of CodeIgniter's loader. Just `include` the file and use it like any other class. you end up tightly coupled but there's no dependency injection in CI, so there's not much you can easily do about it.

```
include( FCPATH . 'application/libraries/mylib.php' );

class Thing extends CI_Controller
{
    public function x()
    {
        $a = new mylib();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, 
You can also `autoload` it using the `config.php` or through the built in `$this->load`

Comment: @Patrick if you read the original question, the poster specifically wants to use the `new` keyword ('the traditional way')

Comment: @Erik i was refering to the point you can still use the `new` keyword with items that are autoloaded or included through the `$this->load`